# discord.py custom profile with bio

Tags: python, json, discord, profile

im trying to code a discord bot where all users have a customizable profile. whenever they run a command `!profile`, the bot will display an embed with bio. the embed will be a custom embed color of their choice and other information like their coins and so on. i want to make it that whenever they run something like `!bio test`, their profile embed will have the message `test`, and if they run `!bio Lorem`, their custom profile bio will be edited to `Lorem` and so on. however when i tried to do the `!bio test` command it doesnt work

```
def saveJson(data, file):
    json.dump(data, open(file, "w"), indent = 4)

@client.command(aliases=["b"])
async def bio(ctx, *, message):
  user = ctx.author.id
  username = str(ctx.author)
    desciption['users'].append({
      'id':user,
      'name':username,
      'description': [message]
    })
    saveJson(description, "./profile.json")
```

later on in the profile command my bot will find the description part in the json file and show it whenever someone checks your profile

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: i tried to  do the !bio command but it doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

The variable is `description`.
You have written `""desciption""['users'].append(...`

Comment: omg i didnt notice the typo. but it still didnt work after i corrected the typo? it says unexpected indent

Comment: It's probably because you have left indentation -

Comment: "  "desciption['users'].append({
      'id':user,
      'name':username,
      'description': [message]
    })

Comment: now it says undefined name description, am i supposed to add something like description=message?

Comment: You can initialize a new dictionary at the start so description={} at the start of the file

Comment: i tried it, theres no longer an error but it doesnt record it into the json file

Comment: have you defined description={} at the start of the file or at the start of the function?

Comment: yes i did, but it doesnt work

Comment: it's probably because it is stored as description={'users':[{...}]} but json doesnt support lists

Comment: you need to convert to dictionary

Comment: you can use description['users'][username]=... instead of description['users'].append(...)

Comment: is it working now?

Comment: how do i convert to dictionary?

Comment: you can use description['users'][username]=... instead of description['users'].append(...) –

Comment: still doesnt work, ```@client.command(aliases=["b"])
async def bio(ctx, *, message):
  user = ctx.author.id
  username = str(ctx.author)
  description['users']['id']=user[user]=username[description]=[message]
  saveJson(description, "./profile.json")
  await ctx.send(f"Your Bio has been set to {message}.")``` is this code correct?